# Are curses(saapa) effective in Kali Yuga?

Tags: yuga, kali-yuga, smriti, parashara

Our Puranas and other Mahagranthas like Ramayana & the Mahabharata contains numerous examples of curses(saap)(& boons ofcourse) and how their effectiveness shape future events.

In Mahabharata itself we find many instances viz;Karna being cursed by his Guru Parasurama,Sri Krishna cursing Aswatthama ,Sri Krishna in turn getting cursed by Gandhari.And, all those curses fructified.

But that was Dwapara.What about Kali Yuga?

Are curses equally effective in this age as well?

Comment: You are posting nice series of questions and answers from Parashar Smriti :-)

Comment: Yes .Thank you.This is the 2nd one.I hope they all add to fellow users' knowledge.:)

Comment: According to me curses work even in present times, even though the person recieving it is unaware of it.But unreasonably cursing a person will add to the karma of the person who curses .So as far as possible purity of thoughts will keep us away from adding to our already overburdened backlog

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the [Parashara Smriti](http://www.astrojyoti.com/pdfs/DevanagariFiles/13Parashara_Smriti.pdf), curses(saapa) are effective in Kali Yuga as well very much like the previous 3 Yugas.Only difference being in the time after which the curses take effect.

For example,In Krita curses effect immediately,in Treta after 10 days,in Dwapara after a month whereas in Kali it takes **1 year** for the curse to  take effect.

The exact Sloka which answers our query is Chapter 1,Sloka 27:

> **Krite Tatkaalikah saapah Tretaayaam Dasamirdinaih|| Dwapare Chaikamasena Kallou Sambatsarenatu||**
>
> **A curse in Krita takes effect immediately,in Treta it does so in 10 days time,in Dwapara after 1 month and in Kali it takes effect after 1
>   year.**

[image]

Comment: >that is as per parashara smriti  But a person who is having black  tongue curses means it will be effective in 24 hours.

Comment: @@Rickross - Krishna says in Vyasa Mahabharata that he can nullify gandhari' curse in a giffy, but gleefully accepts it, unlike Karna and Aswathamma, who couldn't but suffer from the curses. BTW, it took yrs for these curses to come into force in Dwapara also, isn't it?

Comment: @Krishna I don't see any contradictions.You just need to interpret the term "take effect" properly.

Comment: @@Rickross - For interpretation sake one can interpret any thing to mean anything else.

Comment: Isn't it dependent of Degree of Piousness/Purity of Jiva who are cursing.

Comment: In many cases in the Treta Yuga and Dwapara Yuga, the Maharishi/Rishi would curse instantaneously{as mentioned in the scriptures} when they noticed an act, deserving a Curse. But, these Maharishis/Rishis would later , lessen the severity of their curses. Sometimes, they would even give a  Boon to counterbalance the curse.As per the answer above, the system of curses, would take 1 year , to take effect in Kaliyuga.This is good time in hand, to worship God and get nullified the effect of the curse.

Comment: @Krishna as i said before it all depends on ur interpretation.Suppose u sow a seed in soil.Take this point as the utterance of the curse.Now someone can take the point of the "curse stared taking effect" as the time when the seed sprouts(germinates or whatever that is called) and others can take the same point as and when the seed transforms into a full grown tree and start bearing fruits.That's y said i did not find any contradictions.And have faith in saints' words.They are never wrong in whatever they say .U believe in BG only because u have faith in whatever Vyasa has to say.

Comment: Could you briefly provide the authority of Parashar Smriti? As in, where does it sit in  terms of the Vedic canonical texts?

Comment: @user1993 After Srutis (Vedas) the most authoritative Hindu scriptures are the Smritis. And among the Smritis Manu, Yajnavalkya and Parashara are considered as most important however all others are important as well.

Comment: Is Boons also same as curse?

Comment: @K.C.Polai i am not sure on this.

Comment: @Rickross good answer. I see one exception even if consider “take effect” consideration. Parikshit maharaj was cursed that he would die due to takshak bite in 7 days.  That took effect in 7 days in dwapar yuga

Answer (score 3):

Logically curse works if the person receiving the curse is sensitive enough and has a fear factor in them. According to me a curse is to make the person who is receiving it realise their mistake, if they are insensitive like we are nowadays, it may have very less effect or no effect at all. 
A question will arise on what will happen if someone curse non humans like earth or a place? That also I believe has some human factor in it to work. I could understand that the person giving curse if they are at a certain level of mind could make it work despite the fact that we who receive it could be insensitive, but it is a different level where I couldn't describe and is outside my comprehension for now.

Answer (score -1):

No there are curses in kalyug .Because if is it true than why our saints never destroyed Mughal emperor who ruled and killed many Hindus. Where were the curse power when world war happened.where were the curse power when Jews were killed in world war 2 . And what kind of thing is this that what ever u like and when ever u feel u can curse the person and people above mislead us. Because of these people andhvishwas is big problem in india

Comment: Welcome! Answers on this site should be backed up with proper sources. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)